# Add more than one slideshow gallery on one page

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I have used the following code from https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_slideshow_gallery.asp to create this slideshow gallery.

But I have a problem with having more than one slideshow on one page, and therefore would ask if any of you had an idea to write a script for this?

HTML:

```
                <!-- Full-width images with number text -->
            <div class="mySlides">
                <img src="assets/img/kollektion/Shabes HQ-1.jpg" style="width:100%">
            </div>
          
            <div class="mySlides">
                <img src="assets/img/kollektion/Shabes HQ-4.jpg" style="width:100%">
            </div>
          
            <div class="mySlides">
                <img src="assets/img/kollektion/Shabes HQ-1.jpg" style="width:100%">
            </div>
          
            <div class="mySlides">
                <img src="assets/img/kollektion/Shabes HQ-4.jpg" style="width:100%">
            </div>
          
            <div class="mySlides">
                <img src="assets/img/kollektion/Shabes HQ-1.jpg" style="width:100%">
            </div>
          
            <div class="mySlides">
                <img src="assets/img/kollektion/Shabes HQ-4.jpg" style="width:100%">
            </div>
          
            <!-- Next and previous buttons -->
            <a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1)">&#10094;</a>
            <a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1)">&#10095;</a>
          
            <!-- Thumbnail images -->
            <div class="row">
              <div class="column">
                <img class="demo cursor" src="assets/img/kollektion/Shabes HQ-1.jpg" style="width:100%" onclick="currentSlide(1)">
              </div>
              <div class="column">
                <img class="demo cursor" src="assets/img/kollektion/Shabes HQ-4.jpg" style="width:100%" onclick="currentSlide(2)">
              </div>
              <div class="column">
                <img class="demo cursor" src="assets/img/kollektion/Shabes HQ-1.jpg" style="width:100%" onclick="currentSlide(3)">
              </div>
              <div class="column">
                <img class="demo cursor" src="assets/img/kollektion/Shabes HQ-4.jpg" style="width:100%" onclick="currentSlide(4)">
              </div>
              <div class="column">
                <img class="demo cursor" src="assets/img/kollektion/Shabes HQ-1.jpg" style="width:100%" onclick="currentSlide(5)">
              </div>
              <div class="column">
                <img class="demo cursor" src="assets/img/kollektion/Shabes HQ-4.jpg" style="width:100%" onclick="currentSlide(6)">
              </div>
            </div>
```

JS:
var slideIndex = 1;
showSlides(slideIndex);

```
function plusSlides(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex += n);
}

function currentSlide(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex = n);
}

function showSlides(n) {
  var i;
  var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
  var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("demo");
  if (n > slides.length) {slideIndex = 1}
  if (n < 1) {slideIndex = slides.length}
  for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
      slides[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
      dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }
  slides[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";
  dots[slideIndex-1].className += " active";
  captionText.innerHTML = dots[slideIndex-1].alt;
}
enter code here
```

Answer (score 0):

One thing to notice is that the complete slideshow - caption, thumbnails (=demos), prev/next buttons and the actual current slide are all within the element with class container.

We can therefore consider an element with class container to be a whole slide show.

Just copy the whole container element and we have two slide shows in HTML.

Some things need changing. In the JS we pick up each of the container elements and remember their slideIndex in the actual element as a data attribute.

In the plusSlides and currentSlide functions we work out which slide show we are on from the event's target (and its parent(s)).

Also, the caption is defined with an id in the original, we change that to a class so that there can be one for each slide show.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style>
body {
  font-family: Arial;
  margin: 0;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

img {
  vertical-align: middle;
}

/* Position the image container (needed to position the left and right arrows) */
.container {
  position: relative;
}

/* Hide the images by default */
.mySlides {
  display: none;
}

/* Add a pointer when hovering over the thumbnail images */
.cursor {
  cursor: pointer;
}

/* Next & previous buttons */
.prev,
.next {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  top: 40%;
  width: auto;
  padding: 16px;
  margin-top: -50px;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 20px;
  border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;
  user-select: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
}

/* Position the "next button" to the right */
.next {
  right: 0;
  border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
}

/* On hover, add a black background color with a little bit see-through */
.prev:hover,
.next:hover {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
}

/* Number text (1/3 etc) */
.numbertext {
  color: #f2f2f2;
  font-size: 12px;
  padding: 8px 12px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
}

/* Container for image text */
.caption-container {
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #222;
  padding: 2px 16px;
  color: white;
}

.row:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}

/* Six columns side by side */
.column {
  float: left;
  width: 16.66%;
}

/* Add a transparency effect for thumnbail images */
.demo {
  opacity: 0.6;
}

.active,
.demo:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}
</style>
<body>

<h2 style="text-align:center">Slideshow Gallery</h2>

<div class="container">
  <div class="mySlides">
    <div class="numbertext">1 / 6</div>
    <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/howto/img_woods_wide.jpg" style="width:100%">
  </div>

  <div class="mySlides">
    <div class="numbertext">2 / 6</div>
    <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/howto/img_5terre_wide.jpg" style="width:100%">
  </div>

  <div class="mySlides">
    <div class="numbertext">3 / 6</div>
    <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/howto/img_mountains_wide.jpg" style="width:100%">
  </div>
    
  <div class="mySlides">
    <div class="numbertext">4 / 6</div>
    <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/howto/img_lights_wide.jpg" style="width:100%">
  </div>

  <div class="mySlides">
    <div class="numbertext">5 / 6</div>
    <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/howto/img_nature_wide.jpg" style="width:100%">
  </div>
    
  <div class="mySlides">
    <div class="numbertext">6 / 6</div>
    <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/howto/img_snow_wide.jpg" style="width:100%">
  </div>
    
  <a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1)">❮</a>
  <a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1)">❯</a>

  <div class="caption-container">
    <p class="caption"></p>
  </div>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="column">
      <img class="demo cursor" src="https://www.w3schools.com/howto/img_woods.jpg" style="width:100%" onclick="currentSlide(1)" alt="The Woods">
    </div>
    <div class="column">
      <img class="demo cursor" src="https://www.w3schools.com/howto/img_5terre.jpg" style="width:100%" onclick="currentSlide(2)" alt="Cinque Terre">
    </div>
    <div class="column">
      <img class="demo cursor" src="https://www.w3schools.com/howto/img_mountains.jpg" style="width:100%" onclick="currentSlide(3)" alt="Mountains and fjords">
    </div>
    <div class="column">
      <img class="demo cursor" src="https://www.w3schools.com/howto/img_lights.jpg" style="width:100%" onclick="currentSlide(4)" alt="Northern Lights">
    </div>
    <div class="column">
      <img class="demo cursor" src="https://www.w3schools.com/howto/img_nature.jpg" style="width:100%" onclick="currentSlide(5)" alt="Nature and sunrise">
    </div>    
    <div class="column">
      <img class="demo cursor" src="https://www.w3schools.com/howto/img_snow.jpg" style="width:100%" onclick="currentSlide(6)" alt="Snowy Mountains">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<h2 style="text-align:center">Slideshow Gallery</h2>

<div class="container">
  <div class="mySlides">
    <div class="numbertext">1 / 6</div>
    <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/howto/img_woods_wide.jpg" style="width:100%">
  </div>

  <div class="mySlides">
    <div class="numbertext">2 / 6</div>
    <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/howto/img_5terre_wide.jpg" style="width:100%">
  </div>

  <div class="mySlides">
    <div class="numbertext">3 / 6</div>
    <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/howto/img_mountains_wide.jpg" style="width:100%">
  </div>
    
  <div class="mySlides">
    <div class="numbertext">4 / 6</div>
    <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/howto/img_lights_wide.jpg" style="width:100%">
  </div>

  <div class="mySlides">
    <div class="numbertext">5 / 6</div>
    <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/howto/img_nature_wide.jpg" style="width:100%">
  </div>
    
  <div class="mySlides">
    <div class="numbertext">6 / 6</div>
    <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/howto/img_snow_wide.jpg" style="width:100%">
  </div>
    
  <a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1)">❮</a>
  <a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1)">❯</a>

  <div class="caption-container">
    <p class="caption"></p>
  </div>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="column">
      <img class="demo cursor" src="https://www.w3schools.com/howto/img_woods.jpg" style="width:100%" onclick="currentSlide(1)" alt="The Woods">
    </div>
    <div class="column">
      <img class="demo cursor" src="https://www.w3schools.com/howto/img_5terre.jpg" style="width:100%" onclick="currentSlide(2)" alt="Cinque Terre">
    </div>
    <div class="column">
      <img class="demo cursor" src="https://www.w3schools.com/howto/img_mountains.jpg" style="width:100%" onclick="currentSlide(3)" alt="Mountains and fjords">
    </div>
    <div class="column">
      <img class="demo cursor" src="https://www.w3schools.com/howto/img_lights.jpg" style="width:100%" onclick="currentSlide(4)" alt="Northern Lights">
    </div>
    <div class="column">
      <img class="demo cursor" src="https://www.w3schools.com/howto/img_nature.jpg" style="width:100%" onclick="currentSlide(5)" alt="Nature and sunrise">
    </div>    
    <div class="column">
      <img class="demo cursor" src="https://www.w3schools.com/howto/img_snow.jpg" style="width:100%" onclick="currentSlide(6)" alt="Snowy Mountains">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<script>
const slideShows = document.querySelectorAll('.container');

let slideShow, slideIndex; //will be set to the current slideShow as appropriate

for (let i=0; i < slideShows.length; i++) {
  slideShow = slideShows[i];
  slideShow.setAttribute('data-slideIndex', 1); //instead of slideIndex = 1 we remember the index for each slideshow in a data attribute
  slideIndex = 1;
  showSlides(1);
}

function plusSlides(n) {
  slideShow = event.target.parentElement;
  slideIndex = Number(slideShow.getAttribute('data-slideIndex'));
  showSlides(slideIndex += n);
}

function currentSlide(n) {
  slideShow = event.target.parentElement.parentElement.parentElement;
  slideIndex = Number(slideShow.getAttribute('data-slideIndex'));
  showSlides(slideIndex = n);
}

function showSlides(n) {
  var i;
  var slides = slideShow.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
  var dots = slideShow.getElementsByClassName("demo");
  var captionText = slideShow.querySelector(".caption");
  
  if (n > slides.length) {slideIndex = 1}
  if (n < 1) {slideIndex = slides.length}
  for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
      slides[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
      dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }
  slides[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";
  dots[slideIndex-1].className += " active";
  captionText.innerHTML = dots[slideIndex-1].alt;
  
  slideShow.setAttribute('data-slideIndex', slideIndex); // remember the slideIndex for this slideShow
}

</script>
    
</body>
</html>
```

Note: there are various bits of JS in the w3Schools example that look a bit 'old-fashioned' nowadays, but the code works.